# fatal error: rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: rclcpp, errors, buiding-errors

I already build some others packages without errors, but now i'm trying to build a library now and i have this error: fatal error: rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp: No such file or directory
10 | #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp".

I'm using ROS2 Humble on linux 22.04. In my .h file I #include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp". I source with this command source `/opt/ros/humble/setup.bash` and in the same workspace I can build other packages individually.
Many thanks to all of you.

-Here my CMake file-

```
project(TEST_LIB)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)

include_directories(include)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

add_library(TEST_LIB src/TEST_LIB.cpp)
# this line to export the library
ament_export_targets(TEST_LIB HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)

# install the include/arto directory to the install/include/arto
#install (
#  DIRECTORY include/TEST_LIB # This specifies the source directory that you want to install.This directory likely contains header files associated with the arto_lib library.
 # DESTINATION include) # This specifies the destination directory where you want to install the source directory. 

  install (
  TARGETS TEST_LIB # sto  installando gli artefatti generatomi dal cmake di arto_lib, quelli definiti in add_library  
  EXPORT TEST_LIB  # Export permette alla libreria arto_lib di essere esportata ed utilizzata da altri progetti, permettendogli di linkarsi
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib #   This specifies the directory where the built shared libraries (if any) associated with the arto_lib target should be installed. 
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib # This specifies the directory where the built static libraries (if any) associated with the arto_lib target should be installed.  
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin  # This specifies the directory where any executable files generated by the arto_lib target should be installed. USLESS HERE
  INCLUDES DESTINATION include # This specifies the directory where any public header files associated with the arto_lib target should be installed. 

  )


ament_package()
```

And here my package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>TEST_LIB</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="user.user@work.net.com">user</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

    <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>std_msgs</depend>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

`ament_target_dependencies(TEST_LIB rclcpp)`

For more `CMakeLists.txt` examples, have a look a the [examples repository](https://github.com/ros2/examples).

Comment: Many thanks, now it works!